Brown fluid dripping out of the front right side of Honda Odyssey, what is it?
We have a 2013 Honda Odyssey. Today I noticed some brown fluid on the garage floor. There's a small puddle where the car was parked and some drips where it was backed out. I soaked some into a paper towel and smelled it, and it doesn't smell like much of anything.
We had the transmission fluid checked a few months ago and they said it was in good shape.



Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! If I were a betting man, I'd wonder if that isn't some water which is leaking out of a rust through in the body. You might want to physically see where the fluid is coming from. Transmission fluid would be red. Power steering would be clear. If running Honda Smurf juice, it'd be blue for coolant. Oil would look more black than what you're showing. Unless you're running straight water in the engine which has been there for a long time, rusty water is about the only thing I can come up with.
